# When to use an object in `setState` instead of using functional `setState`?

Tags: reactjs

I read a lot of articles about using functional `setState` like that:

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({   counter: state.counter + props.increment }));
```

but when do we actually need to use it as an object like that:

```
this.setState({quantity: 2})
```

Is there a significant reason why we should use an object in `setState` in normal cases vs using it as a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm is to use an object, it's also less code and easier to read. The only reason u want to use a function setState is when u need to access the previous state.

consider the following example

```
// you have a switch state

state = {
   checked: false
}

// .. and later in an onChange method 

onChange = () => {
   const {checked} = this.state;
   // this is problematic because react works in an async fashion, so it could be that when this function was called checked was false, however it was only executed later when checked was actually true 
   this.setState({checked: !checked} 

  // on the other hand  this form is safe, even if things were happening async, you are safe because you act on the most updated state 
   this.setState(prvState => {...prvState, checked: !prvState.checked})
}
```

Comment: so we mostly use an object for the sake of readability? no advantages performance-wise?

Comment: @RowanX yea an object should be the norm, its easier to read that code also. a function should be used when the updated state depends on a previous state or props, to ensure safety. From a performance point of view react documentation mentions nothing of this, in fact if u think if it the function will  require an extra call stack frame ( and so more memory and cpu instructions). However this is just a an extremely tiny difference. Bottom line performance wise there should be no observable difference.

Comment: React components are always transpiled first. Use of an object instead of a function will not give any performance benefit. Likewise, the use of a function instead of an object will not slow down the code or make it less readable. (When the object to be set has lot of attributes, then the use of a function will actually make the code more readable.)  The choice is completely based on convenience and the scenario being handled. Both the approaches are right. Both will give the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, ***a function is an object***.

Therefore, technically, there is no difference between

- a function being passed as the argument to setState and
- an object being passed as the argument for the setState method.

However, a function may be used instead of an object for the purpose of formatting or for performing temporary calculations before updating the state attributes.

**Example use cases for function in place of an object:**

1. Rounding-off decimal places
2. Conversion of units (Celcius --> fahrenheit, KG to lb, etc)
3. Compute derived information (max, min, average, etc)

Comment: This is not correct, there is a huge difference between an object and a function. Yes any non primitive data type in javascript is originally an object, but that does it mean that there is no difference. They are not interchangeable,  and specifically in react setState method  if u place an object instead of a function, and u use prv state in that object, then if react batch state updates for performance reasons, you might eventually have incorrect state in your component

Comment: Every function in Javascript is an object. More information can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions. Also, React state change happens in atomic manner. There is no case of a state being in between two values. Therefore, the use of function instead of an object inside setState will not have any technical side-effects.